# Warning in ag-Grid: You are mixing modules (i.e. @ag-grid-community/core) and packages (ag-grid-community)

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

i'm using these npm modules for the ag-grid:

```
"@ag-grid-community/react": "^25.0.1",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "25.0.1",
"ag-grid-community": "^25.0.1",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^25.0.1",
"ag-grid-react": "^25.0.1",
```

and these imports :

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
  import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
  import { ModuleRegistry, AllModules } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules';
  import '@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
  import '@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css';
  import { LicenseManager } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/core';
    
  LicenseManager.setLicenseKey(
      'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  );
  ModuleRegistry.registerModules(AllModules);
```

Why i'm getting this warning in the console and how i can get rid of it ?

```
ag-Grid: You are mixing modules (i.e. @ag-grid-community/core) and packages (ag-grid-community) - you can only use one or the other of these mechanisms.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the warning because quite simply, you are mixing modules and packages. The library `ag-grid-community` contains everything in ag-Grid community whereas `@ag-grid-community/core` contains the core items from ag-Grid community. You need to install one or the other, depending on whether you are using modules or packages.

From ag-Grid:

> There are two main ways to install ag-Grid - either by using packages
> , or by using modules. packages are the easiest way to use ag-Grid,
> but by default include all code specific to each package, whereas
> modules allow you to cherry pick what functionality you want, which
> will allow for a reduced overall bundle size.

Take a look at the documentation around packages and modules [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/packages-modules/).

Answer (score 2):

You only need the following in your package.json file as these packages contain all the code you need following the AG Grid 'package' approach.

```json
"ag-grid-community": "^25.0.1",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^25.0.1",
"ag-grid-react": "^25.0.1",
```

From the [docs](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/modules/#mixing-packages-and-modules)

> It is important that you do not mix packages and modules in the same
> application as this will result in AG Grid being included twice and
> doubling your bundle size! All modules are scoped by either
> @ag-grid-community/* or @ag-grid-enterprise/* and should not be mixed
> with the standalone packages of ag-grid-community and
> ag-grid-enterprise.

| Modules | Packages |
| --- | --- |
| @ag-grid-community/xxxxx | ag-grid-community |
| @ag-grid-enterprise/xxxxx | ag-grid-enterprise |

I have written about this more in this [blog post](https://blog.ag-grid.com/minimising-bundle-size/).